# I am using manim version v0.17.03 and trying to animate scene by focusing camera on a specific shape, but am unable to use camera help me

Tags: python, manim

I am trying this code :-

```
class CameraFocusing(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        s = Square(color=YELLOW).move_to(np.array([-4,0,0]))
        c = Circle().move_to(np.array([4,0,0]))
        self.add(s,c)
        self.wait(3)
        
        self.camera.frame_center = s.get_center()
        self.wait(3)
        
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.shift(8 * RIGHT))
        self.wait(2)
```

type here

```
        
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            config.pixel_height = 720
            config.pixel_width = 1280
            config.frame_height = 7.0
            config.frame_width = 7.0
            config.frame_center = [-4, 0, 0]
            config.background_color = BLACK
            config.pixel_height = 720
            config.pixel_width = 1280
            config.save_as_gif = True
            config.quality = "medium"
            config.media_height = 7.0
            config.media_width = 7.0

            scene = CameraFocusing()
            scene.render()
```

but whenever i am trying to execute this, i get this Attribute error:-

AttributeError: 'Camera' object has no attribute 'frame'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.